setTimeout method confusing scope of "this" keyword in Angular 17 app
I'm trying to achieve an animation that functions pretty much the same as a stopwatch.  In my component I have a function which looks like this
private count():void{
    const currentYear : number = new Date().getFullYear();
    /*const exp : number = this.Data ? currentYear - this.Data : 0;*/

    /* this is just for testing purpose but the commented line above is what
    I'd actually like to work with*/
    const exp : number = 23;

    for(let i = 0; i < exp; i++){
      setTimeout(()=>{

        //this is a variable defined on my component
        this.Experience++;
      }, 30);
    }
}

When I comment out the setTimeout() method the Experience variable increments but when I add it back in my page stalls out as if stuck in an infinite loop.  I looked into the setTimeout() method and noticed the documentation said this

When you pass a method to setTimeout(), it will be invoked with a this value that may differ from your expectation.

After reading that I'm assuming targeting this.Experience on the component must be confusing the setTimout() method as it may be searching within it's own scope for the variable rather than the scope of the component.  Does anybody know how I can work around this or another way I can achieve this functionality?

I think you want 30 * i. You are setting a bunch of timeouts that all finish at exactly the same time. this is not related to your problem. You're using a fat arrow function => which does not re-bind this. You are also not passing a method, which would look like setTimeout(someObj.method, 30);

so are you saying I should put the this.Experience++ part in a separate function and pass that into the setTimeout()?  Also note that I'm not actually using the animations module or anything for this.  I just want to increment the variable up by 1 ever few milliseconds.  I just started with 30 just as a starting point but may want it to work faster than that.  I figured the for loop would pause for that long and continue to the next iteration until the condition is met.  How are they all finishing at the same time rather than in succession one after another?

export class SampleClass {
  private Experience: number = 0;

  startCount() {
    this.count();
  }

  private count(): void {
    const exp: number = 23;

    repeatAction(() => {
      this.Experience++;
    }, exp);

    function repeatAction(
      action: () => void,
      times: number,
      delayInMilliSeconds = 30
    ) {
      let count = 0;

      function executeAction() {
        if (count < times) {
          count++;
          action();
          setTimeout(executeAction, delayInMilliSeconds);
        }
      }

      executeAction();
    }
  }
}

The repeatAction function Calls an action, in this case incrementing this.Experience, n number of times. The delay between each call can be specified using the delayInMilliseconds argument.

The for loop has a setTimeout inside it, so the loop create a lot of asynchronous actions, which execute after the synchronous code completes. Ideally it should work, but the async tasks are getting executed immediately, so that might be why you are getting this issue.
It's better to opt for setInterval which basically does the same thing and you can clear the interval, once the break condition is met:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div class="exp-box">
        {{Experience}}
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
  .exp-box {
    height:100px;width:100px;background-color: black; color: white;
    display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;font-weight:50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  `,
  ],
})
export class App {
  Experience = 0;
  Data = 2014;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.count();
  }

  private count(): void {
    const currentYear: number = new Date().getFullYear();
    const exp: number = this.Data ? currentYear - this.Data : 0;
    let i = 0;
    const intervalRef = setInterval(() => {
      this.Experience++;
      if (i > exp) {
        clearInterval(intervalRef);
      }
      i++;
    }, 30);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo
